# How to free a char* that will be returned?

Tags: c, malloc, free

Say I have the function below :

```
char* fakeTrim(char* input) {
    char* temp = malloc(strlen(input));
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if(input[i] != ' ')
            temp[count++] = input[i];
    }
    temp[count] = '\0';
    return temp;
}
```

Does the temp cause any memory leakage?
IF so, is it possible to free it before we return temp?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it causes memory leak, you can free it in the caller for fakeTrim(), when you feel it is no more required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, of course you can't free memory that belongs to the data you're returning.  And indeed allocating memory within a utility function like this makes memory leaks extremely likely; since the caller won't see the function body, it will be very easy for her to forget to free it.  There is a standard solution to this issue actually, and that is to make the caller allocate the memory himself:

```
void fakeTrim(const char* input, char* temp) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if(input[i] != ' ')
            temp[count++] = input[i];
    }
    temp[count] = '\0';
}
```

Now memory leaks are still possible but it's not 'your fault'--the caller should know to free memory that he allocates.  Note the addition of `const` in the signature makes which argument is input, and which is output, clear.

Edit: Here's a use case:

```
const char* input = "Hello world";
char* temp = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
fakeTrim(input, temp);
// ... do something with temp
free(temp);
```

Comment: How would the caller exactly free the memory leak?
Say char* str = fakeTrim("hello");
free(str); ?

Comment: @user3471059 I added an example of how the caller would use it.  But basically, yes, the call to `free` would come after `temp` was used to whatever purpose it was intended.

Comment: Since `fakeTrim` never adds characters, another option would be to make it in-place, e.g. `void fakeTrim(char *input_and_output)`

Comment: @MattMcNabb True, but then the caller would also be responsible for copying `input` to a new string if he wanted to also use `input` after the call to `fakeTrim`.  But granted many trim functions work this way so that could also be a good option for OP.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only free the allocated memory when you no longer need to refer to it, which means that the caller needs to free the returned value (and you should mention this in the documentation for the function).

By the way, you will end up with an out-of-bounds array reference on `temp[count] = '\0';` if your input string has no spaces in it, so you should allocate one more byte. (And `trim` doesn't usually remove internal spaces, but perhaps that is why you called it `fakeTrim`.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Indeed temp will cause memory leakage.

However, I have an alternative solution for a requirement of yours.
You can make use of a dynamic variable in the caller function by using pass by reference and later free it from the caller function itself (No need to free it from the called function). Please see below:

```
void main()
{
        char *test;

        setVal(test);
        puts(test);
        if(test){
                free(test);
                test = NULL;
        }
}
void setVal(char **data)
{
        char retry[100]="This is test";
        char *ret;

        ret = malloc((strlen(retry))*sizeof(char));
        if(ret == NULL)
                exit(1);
        strncpy(ret, retry, strlen(retry));

        *data = ret;
}
```

If you are still not satisfied. Use the sample codes I have provided with VALGRIND to see if there is any memory leakage.

Hope it helps.